# Show parent child taxonomy in nested tabs with its post

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy

I want to show parent taxonomy in tab section and the under parent taxonomy i want to display child taxonomy in nested tab. On selection of child taxonomy i want to show its post. I am getting every time child taxonomy with with its post which i don't want.

**Here is what i want:**

```
TAB1(parent active) TAB2(parent)

ALL_TAB1(child active) SUB1_TAB1 SUB2_TAB1

(posts for all, sub1_tab1, sub2_tab1 and respectively whichever is active)
```

**What i tried**

```
<?php 
/*
Template Name: Prac
*/

 get_header(); 

// Get list of 'categories' for tabs -->
$args = array(
'hide_empty' => false,
'parent' => 0
);
$preferences = get_terms( 'preferences', $args );
?>


<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">

  <?php
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
      the_content(); 
    endwhile; ?>

    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">

        <!-- Create the tabs -->
        <?php
        // Use counter so that 'active' class is only applied to first tab
        $counter = 0;
        foreach ($preferences as $preference) { ?>

            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link <?= ($counter == 0) ? 'active' : '' ?>" id="<?php echo $preference->slug;?>-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#<?php echo $preference->slug; ?>" role="tab" aria-controls="<?php echo $preference->slug;?>" aria-selected="<?= ($counter == 0) ? 'true' : 'false' ?>"><?php echo $preference->name; ?></a>
            </li>

        <?php $counter++; } ?>

    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
    <!-- Get the content for each tab -->
    <?php
    $counter2 = 0;
    foreach ($preferences as $preference) { ?>

        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade <?= ($counter2 == 0) ? 'show active' : '' ?>" id="<?php echo $preference->slug; ?>"  aria-labelledby="<?php echo $preference->slug; ?>-tab">
            <div class="row">
                <?php
                    $args = array(
                        'post_type' => 'project',
                        'tax_query' => array(
                            array(
                                'taxonomy' => $preference->taxonomy,
                                'field'    => $preference->slug,
                                'terms'    => $preference->term_id
                            )
                        )
                    );

                    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
                ?>
                <div class="col-md-6" id="<?php echo $preference->slug . '-clauses' ?>">
                     <?php
                            ?>
                    <?php 

                        if ( $loop->have_posts() ) : while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
                            <?php
                            //Do something if a specific array value exists within a post
                            $term_list = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, $preference->taxonomy, array("fields" => "all"));
                            ?>
                          <?php foreach($term_list as $term_single) { 
                                $category_children = get_terms(array(
                                    'parent'    => $term_single->term_id,
                                    'hide_empty' => false
                                    ) );
                                $category_children_count = count($category_children);
                            ?>

                            <?php } ?>
                             <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a href="#<?php echo $term_single->slug; ?>" class="nav-link" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><?php echo $term_single->name; ?></a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <a class="col-md-6" href="<?php echo the_permalink();?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail();?><?php echo the_title(); ?></a>
                    <?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
                </div>
            </div> <!-- end row -->

        </div> <!-- end tab-pane -->
        <?php $counter2++; } ?>
    </div> <!-- end tab-content -->

</div> <!-- end col -->
</div> <!-- end row --> 

<!-- end content -->
 <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

**I am getting like this**

```
TAB1 TAB2

SUB1_TAB1
    post
SUB1_TAB1
    post
SUB1_TAB2
```

Can anyone help ? Thanks.